# ajax get method

Tags: php, ajax

UPDATE... this is the code I've implemented from the tutorial, within chrome dev tools in network i can see in header the variable is being sent and in preview i can see the drop down menu however it is not inserted into the loaded webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectEvidence').change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
        });
    });  

function evidencesearch(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("case").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("case").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","searchfunction.php?variable="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}       
</script>


<?php
$variable = $_GET['variable']; //used for second drop down menu
//echo "test test test $variable";

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'fid';


$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$conn)
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db);

echo '<label class="input" for="case" type="input">Specify: </label><select id="case" name="case"><option=value"null"></option>'; //Insert to loaded page
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT $variable FROM `evidence`");
if($resource && mysql_num_rows($resource)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)){
         echo '<option value="'.$row[$variable].'">'.$row[$variable].'</option></select>';//Insert to loaded page
    }
}
mysql_close($conn)
?>
```

Comment: i did look into jquery however i've manged to get is displaying the drop down menu on the page it was an issue with calling the div by its class rather than id. I just have a problem with my sql statement breaking now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem sticks within POST/GET functions; try to call them synchronously and paste please the w3schools tutorial's link you mentioned. Maybe I can help you then by writing more detailed answer.

Cheers.

Comment: I've been looking at this tutorial and rather than creating a table creating a drop down menu http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp I can add my updated code with it implemented if that helps?